# Python reading file into two lists of integers

Tags: python, list, loops, readfile

I wanted to read a file and extract two lists of doubles
for example, file.txt contains the following:

```
123 345 456 8919
231 521 363 1716
```

separated by a white space ' '. I have the following code to read the above file:

```
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        for line in f.readline():
            cipher_array.append(line.split()[0])
            cipher_array.append(line.split()[1])
            halfmask.append(line.split()[2]) 
            halfmask.append(line.split()[3])
```

I get the following error:

```
 cipher_array.append(line.split()[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I want to have cipher_array to consist of [123, 345, 231, 521] and halfmask = [456, 8919, 363, 1716]

What is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance

Comment: use `split(" ")` instead of split()

Comment: `f.readline()` should be `f.readlines()`

Comment: Actually it should just be `for line in f:`

Comment: Thank you everyone! everything you said fixed it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `split(" ")` instead of `split()` also
`f.readline()` should be `f.readlines()`

```
cipher_array,halfmask=[],[]
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        cipher_array.append(float(line.split(" ")[0]))
        cipher_array.append(float(line.split(" ")[1]))
        halfmask.append(float(line.split(" ")[2]) )
        halfmask.append(float(line.split(" ")[3]))
cipher_array,halfmask
```

[image: code image]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [`f.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), which will read a single line, and then iterate over it, hence your `line` variable is a single character. You probably meant `readlines` instead of `readline`. It is better to iterate directly over the file object, though:

```
for line in f:
```

You will also need to `strip()` line of the trailing whitespace and then convert the results of `split` into `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating on single line as on `f.readline()`, which will return a line, to see try:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
  print(f.readline()) # will return 123 345 456 8919
```

So, you can iterate through file as follows:

```
numbers = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    numbers.extend(line.split())
numbers = list(map(int, numbers))
numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that `f.readline()` reads only the first line of the file, so the loop is only executed once. Replace it with `f.readlines()`. (note the s at the end)